# Unable to load the data from file to Mysql table

Tags: mysql

I am unable to load the data from file to a MySQL table.

Where else should I keep the file?

File is present as shown below.

```
notroot@ubuntu:~/lab/data$ ls
txns

notroot@ubuntu:~/lab/data$ pwd

/home/notroot/lab/data

notroot@ubuntu:~/lab/data$ mysql -u root -p

mysql> load data infile '/home/notroot/lab/data/txns' into table trans fields terminated by ',' lines terminated by '\n';
ERROR 29 (HY000): File '/home/notroot/lab/data/txns' not found (Errcode: 13)

mysql> load data local infile '/home/notroot/lab/data/txns' into table trans fields terminated by ',' lines terminated by '\n';
ERROR 1148 (42000): The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version
mysql>
```

Comment: Show us the output of `cat /home/notroot/lab/data/txns`, or a portion of it if it's so big

Comment: notroot@ubuntu:~$ head -5 /home/notroot/lab/data/txns
00000000,06-26-2011,4007024,040.33,Exercise & Fitness,Cardio Machine Accessories,Clarksville,Tennessee,credit
00000001,05-26-2011,4006742,198.44,Exercise & Fitness,Weightlifting Gloves,Long Beach,California,credit
00000002,06-01-2011,4009775,005.58,Exercise & Fitness,Weightlifting Machine Accessories,Anaheim,California,credit
00000003,06-05-2011,4002199,198.19,Gymnastics,Gymnastics Rings,Milwaukee,Wisconsin,credit
00000004,12-17-2011,4002613,098.81,Team Sports,Field Hockey,Nashville  ,Tennessee,credit

Answer (score 0):

Use the `--local-infile` parameter when running `mysql`

```
mysql --local-infile -u root -p
```

Comment: thanks a lot. i tried this but still i get the same error